# Calculation of a text value, The value of which is separated by a special character

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, field-calculator

How can I calculate a text value, the value of which is separated by a special character?

For example: `dog | duck`, I would like to keep the first value: `dog`
or
`elephant | cat`,  I want to keep `elephant`.

The length of characters are different.

Answer (score 4):

Try using the `.split` Python function in the field calculator.  If, for example, you have `dog|cat`, the `.split("|")` function splits the string by `|` into two parts `['dog', 'cat']`.  The `[0]` at the end of the function states that you want the first of the two items in the list.  Finally, to be sure there are no remaining spaces in the rows, use `.strip()`

[image]

Comment: He should split on `" | "` (with spaces) instead of `"|"` right?

Comment: Good call @Erica, this will be sensitive to spaces if indeed there are any in the field.  Otherwise there will be spaces left over.

Comment: it would be safer to remove the spaces after the split. Like this : !field!.split("|")[0].strip()